# Relative path not working as expected in PHP?

Tags: php, path

I'm using a script I got on Code Canyon called XCRUD.  As the name implies it creates CRUD forms.  But I'm having trouble making it work when the server changes (i.e. local development to production).

Its configuration consists of setting a bunch of properties in a config class.  One in particular is a file path:

```
public static $scripts_url = 'xcrud'; 
// URL to the xCRUD folder, not real path, without a trailing slash, can be relative, 
e.g. 'some_folder/xcrud' or absolute, e.g. 'http://www.your_site.com/some_folder/xcrud'
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to find a way to enter a relative path that actually works in multiple server locations.

For example let's say I have the following 3 environments to deal with:

1. Local Development: `http://localhost:8888/site/`
2. Production Testing: `http://urltest.com/dept/site/`
3. Production Live:  `http://url.com/dept/site/`

If I set the xcrud path to `site/xcrud` it works for 1, but not 2 or 3.  So it's not behaving the way I thought a relative path would.

My current "solution" is a switch statement defining a constant with absolute path based on `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and what I know the path would be in those 3 environments, then using that constant as the path in config.  But that's not exactly flexible and seems like the wrong way to do it:

```
    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
        case "localhost":
           define('MY_SERVER_PATH', 'http://localhost:8888/site/xcrud');
           break;
        case "urltest.com":
           define('MY_SERVER_PATH', 'http://urltest.com/dept/site/xcrud');
           break;
        case "url.com":
           define('MY_SERVER_PATH', 'http://url.com/dept/site/xcrud');
           break;
    }

    public static $scripts_url = MY_SERVER_PATH;
```

There's got to be a better way, right?

Comment: how do you use scripts_url ?

Comment: Question: why does your development server not mirror testing & production as it should? If you'd develop in `http://localhost:8888/dept/site`, you could probably get away with `/dept/site/xcrud` in all 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some config files since you are using multiple environments. This way it's possible to load different values for each envoirment (such as database credentials or your crud urls).

With the config structure you only have to check for the environment once somewhere in the beginning of your app.

```
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case "localhost":
        // Load localhost config file
       break;
    case "urltest.com":
       // Load urltest config file
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try v1.6. It has url path autodetection, just leave `$scripts_url` empty :)